# Why can't I see Loading... while scrolling?

Tags: python, jquery, django, django-views, django-templates

Based on [this tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/03/13/how-to-create-infinite-scroll-with-django.html)

This is my views:

```
def All( request  ):
    p=product.objects.all().order_by('id')
    pa=Paginator(p,20)
    page=request.GET.get('page')
    pro=pa.get_page(page)
    return render(request,'home.html',{'pro':pro})
```

This is my template:

```
<div class="grid">  
  
         {%for p in pro%} 
                <div class='card'>
                    <img src="{{p.image}}"></img>
                    <p id="id">{{p.description}}</p>
                    <a href="{{p.buy}}" target='_blank' rel='noopener noreferrer'>
                        <button ><span class="price"> ${{p.price}}</span> buy</button>
                    </a>    




                </div>
    
         {%endfor%} 
         {% if pro.has_next %}
            <a class='more-link' href="?page={{pro.next_page_number}}">Next</a>
         {% endif %}
         <div class="loading" style="display: none;">
                Loading...
         </div>
         <script>
                    var infinite = new Waypoint.Infinite({
                      element: $('.grid')[0],
                      onBeforePageLoad: function () {
                        $('.loading').show();
                      },
                      onAfterPageLoad: function ($items) {
                        $('.loading').hide();
                      }
                    });
         </script>
</div>
```

I have downloaded dependencies correctly and I included some links in my html to use them, but currently I'm not able to find what is wrong with my code.

[server response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6NVF.png)

Why can't I see `Loading...` while scrolling?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: you should check JavaScript console in DevTools in browser to see if you don't get any error in JavaScript. Maybe you don't load JavaScript module with class `Waypoint`

Comment: or maybe page loads very fast and it displays text very short time and simply you can't see this text. You could use `alert()` or `console.log()` in `onBeforePageLoad` and `onAfterPageLoad` to see if they are executed.